# Calculating Inter Annotator Agreement with brat annotated files

Tags: python, annotations, brat

With three annotators we have been using brat (http://brat.nlplab.org/) to annotate a sample of texts for three categories: PERS, ORG, GPE. I want to calculate Inter Annotator Agreement for that sample. However, I do not seem to find a simple way to do it. I have tried this Python package: https://github.com/savkov/BratUtils , but it seems to fail.

For each annotated sample I have three .ann files for which I want to calculate Inter Annotator Agreement. The data in the files looks like this:

```
T1  Person 173 183  Alexanders
T2  Person 444 450  Hannah
T3  Person 754 766  Corneliszoon
T4  GPE 787 796 Antwerpen
T5  Person 824 833  Alexander
```

Is there a simple way to calculate Inter Annotator Agreement (using Python or a web-based tool)?

Comment: any update on this? did you find any other working scripts?

Comment: I'd like to know too. I haven't reached that stage, but a script might be useful. Does the administrator page not provide this?

Answer (score 1):

I've designed a tool for computing agreement of annotators. It's mostly addressed to Doccano, but with few adjustments, it might be able to compute anything. Please have a look: https://github.com/vwoloszyn/diaa/